# FilePond get uploaded file and download it

Tags: php, laravel, filepond

Im trying to show the uploaded file to the filepond and download it.

i can add it on the filepond field but it count as another file that need to be uploaded.

Here my FilePond code

```
FilePond.setOptions({
    allowMultiple: true,
    instantUpload: false,
    server: {
        url: BASE_URL,
        timeout: 7000,
        
    },
});
```

Add the data

```
var files = data.attachments_path;
var filesLengths = files.length;
for (var j = 0; j < filesLengths; j++) {
    console.log(files[j]);
    ponds.addFiles(files[j]);
}
```

is there anyway to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the initial files list as an array on the `files` property.

```js
const pond = FilePond.create({
    files: [
        {
            // The id of the file
            source: '12345',

            // A 'local' file has been uploaded
            // to the server in a previous sessions
            options: {
                type: 'local',
            },
        },
    ],
});
```

See: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/properties/#files

Comment: How do you use this in a component that uses React-hooks? I'm getting and error on FilePond.create - Property 'create' does not exist on type 'typeof FilePond'.